# Getting error while writing list of dictionaries to Json File

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

Trying to write list of dictionaries to Json File using below code but getting error.

**Input**

```
lst :  [{ '_id': ObjectId('620b7bb7d174648bd95cb105'), 'Name': 'Naveen',  'Id': '19', 'Session_Id': '123456'}]
```

**Code Tried**

```
with open('output.json', 'w') as fout:
    json.dump(lst, fout)
```

**Error Getting**

```
TypeError: Object of type ObjectId is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Can you take a look at your complete code or lst content, I executed it without any problems, or see if there is a problem with your complete lst format, for example, there are some objects in the list that cannot be serialized

Comment: is there any way to identified which objects in the list are not serialized

Comment: Please post the full code and full traceback you are getting. If I copy/paste your code and correct the dict to: `{'lst':  [{'Name': 'Naveen',  'Id': '19', 'Session_Id': '123456'}]}` because `lst :  [{'Name': 'Naveen',  'Id': '19', 'Session_Id': '123456'}]` is not a valid dictionary, it works fine.

Comment: Updated the data. error is getting bcz of Id object in the data

Comment: Well, as the error says, that is not a valid json.

Comment: is there any solution to handle this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input does not seem like valid JSON to me, since you are missing the `{ }` brackets to state that it is JSON. Also, after the name `"Naveen"`, you are missing another `'`.

```
{
   "list":[
      {
         "Name":"Naveen",
         "Id":"19",
         "Session_Id":"123456"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: This now works for me :-)

Comment: But I am still getting the error

Comment: Updated the data. error is getting bcz of Id object in the data

Comment: That's weird, fine on my end ... glad its sorted for you though :D